# How does one detect if the next char is ^?

Tags: macros

How do I do this? Using `\@ifnextchar^{command1}{command2}` fails to work. What should I do instead to detect ^?

**UPDATE.** There turned out to be no problem with the command, just a conflict of names elsewhere in my macro-definitions. Thanks for the fast reaction!

Comment: That would work, if you think it isn't working please provide an example code

Comment: A common oversight is to not put this between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` in the preamble. If these are present, it should work.

Comment: \documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\makeatletter
 \def\logr#1{\@ifnextchar_{\logr@{#1}}{\logr@{#1}_{bot}}}
    \def\logr@#1_#2{\@ifnextchar^{\logr@@{#1}_{#2}}{\logr@@{#1}_{#2}^{top}}}
    \def\logr@@#1_#2^#3{\text{Obj}(#1),\ \text{Basis}(#2),\ \text{Potenz}(#3).}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
 Befehle austesten:    

 $\begin{array}[t]{l}
  \logr{507}\\
        \logr{507}_{b}\\
        \logr{507}^{p}\\
        \logr{507}_{b}^{p}\\
 \end{array}$

\end{document}

Comment: which … works… hmm

Comment: @Thomas code in comments doesn't really work as you see, but you can edit the question and add it to a code block (the `{}` button in the editor)

Comment: Shouldn’t this question be closed as a nonexistent problem?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue is due to a different reason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works with `^` or with the command `\sp`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\foo}{%
  \@ifnextchar\sp{\cmdone}{\cmdtwo}
}

\newcommand{\cmdone}{\text{Is superscripted!}}
\newcommand{\cmdtwo}{\text{Is not superscripted!}}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

$\foo^2$

$\foo E=mc^2$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The following latex file produces a terminal output of

```
yes
no
```

showing that `\@ifnextchar` has tested true for `^` and false for `!`

```
\makeatletter

\@ifnextchar^{\typeout{yes}\@gobble}{\typeout{no}\@gobble}^

\@ifnextchar^{\typeout{yes}\@gobble}{\typeout{no}\@gobble}!

\stop
```